# image_downloader package error: 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'is Pending', 'is Successful' branches or 'else' branch instead

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I want to use the [image_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader) package in my flutter app.

I added it in the pubspec.yaml.

When I run the app I got this Kotlin-related error:

```
    C:\Users\Yassine\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\image_downloader-0.31.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\ko2ic\imagedownloader\ImageDownloaderPlugin.kt: (332, 17): 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'is Pending', 'is Successful' branches or 'else' branch instead

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_downloader:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
```

I use `Flutter version 3.10.5`, and `Android SDK version 33.0.1`.

Have anyone faced this error before?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your `Kotlin` version or you can try to solve this issue by checking you are using the latest version of the `image_downloader` package.

**For that:**

**1. Remove the `image_downloader` package first from `pubspec.yaml`.**

**2. Now add the `image_downloader` package using the command in `terminal`.**

```
flutter pub add image_downloader
```

**3. You can try another solution: to downgrade your `Kolin` version. [Do this if the above method does not work]. To downgrade, Go to `android/build.gradele` file then change the version `'1.4.32'`.**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    // ...
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It seems that the issue is from the package itself, here is the [opened issue on GitHub.](https://github.com/ko2ic/image_downloader/issues/139)

Answer (score 0):

From this [issue](https://github.com/ko2ic/image_downloader/issues/130#issuecomment-1707951113), add this in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  image_downloader:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/VikasTailorbird/image_downloader
```